# How do I change date format at top of day in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, formatting, date

I can change the date format for most dates displayed by my calendar to Irish format, however I can’t find how to change this one.

[image]

The dates at the top of each day are shown as 5/17 or Month/Day—as a European, I would like to be able to display them as 17/5, but that doesn’t seem to be possible from my reading of the configuration settings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Go to **Settings** (Cog wheel on the upper-right side)
2. Search for **Date format**
   [image]
3. Switch to **31/12/2012**
4. Click **Save** at to the or bottom of the settings page

[image]

Comment: I could have sworn I tried that, thank you.

Comment: Hah, also worked for me. I've had yyyy-MM-dd format, which was also causing the dates on the top of the day displayed in reverse format. Quite confusing ;)

Comment: This behaviour is clearly a bug. I prefer yyyy-MM-dd format everywhere and have configured that in the settings, but the day headings aren't displaying as that, they are displaying as MM/dd, which is simply wrong. (The '-' vs '/' indicates the order of components for me.)

Comment: Ah, it's this bug: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/tmO2FFCeeBM